# Strange rendering issues when using xvfb-run

Tags: python, vnc, xvfb

I have an app running remotely on a beaglebone, written in wxPython. I want to run the app inside of a virtual frame buffer, using Xvfb, and access it remotely using a VNC.

It may also be pertinent for you to know that I am launching VNC from inside of the application, like so:

```
    display = Display(":99")
    root = display.screen().root
    win_ids = [w.id for w in root.query_tree()._data['children'] if w.get_wm_name() and 'myappname' in w.get_wm_name().lower()]
    if (win_ids[0]):
       print("Found my win id. Starting x11vnc")
       system("x11vnc -quiet -sid %s -forever &" % win_ids[0])
    else:
        print("Can't find my Window ID!")
```

EDIT: I am using Debian Jessie with kernel version 3.8.13, and xenomai. I can't find a version number for xvfb-run or Xvfb, but I can tell you that my xorg version is 1.16.4

When I launch the app with:

```
    sudo xvfb-run ./myApp -s :99 -screen 0 1920x1080x16 -ac
```

I see the following:
[image: screenshot]

However, when I launch Xvfb separately:

```
    Xvfb :99 -screen 0 800x600x16 -ac &
```

and then launch the app:

```
    DISPLAY=:99 ./myApp
```

I see this (what it should be):

[image: screenshot]

Any insights?

Comment: You are using `sudo` in the first command but not in the second.  Does root have the same fonts installed as the user you're running the app?  i.e. did you install fonts just for the user?

Comment: @grochmal I'm afraid it has no effect.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that in `sudo xvfb-run ./myApp -s :99 -screen 0 1920x1080x16 -ac` the process of `./myApp` ends in root's environment.  Whilst in `DISPLAY=:99 ./myApp` the process uses the environment of the **user that started** it and Xorg routes the actual display to `Xvfb`'s.  Fonts are loaded before the Xorg routing.

Comment: @grochmal Perhaps. But, like I said, I tried running xvfb-run without sudo, and it had the exact same effect.

Comment: Fair enough, but what do you understand as "the same effect" (bad display or good display?).  I need to say ti is pretty hard to guess what you mean by your answers (i'm not in your head).  Still, after looking through `xvfb-run` i noticed that it runs the parameters in the order they appear.  Does the same happen (bad display) if you run it as: `sudo xvfb-run -s :99 -screen 0 1920x1080x16 -ac ./myApp`?

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity. To be very clear: no matter how I lay out the command, xvfb-run always gives me a UI like in the first picture (bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We clearly don't have the same version of `xvfb-run`, but mine is a shell
script and when you run

```
xvfb-run ./myApp -s :99 -screen 0 1920x1080x16 -ac
```

no arguments at all are passed on to the Xvfb server, and all the arguments go to the application.  The application has to be last on the line for options like `-s 1920x1080x16` to be passed to the server.  Without this the default depth of the screen in **8 bits**, which might be the cause of your appearance problems.

---

Also, the args to pass to the server (after `-s`) must be made into a single sting. 
So finally, run:

```
xvfb-run -s '-screen 0 1920x1080x16' ./myApp
```

Comment: Simply running it as `xvfb-run ./myApp -s 1920x1080x16` doesn't fix it. I don't know what the xvfb-run help page says for you, but for me it says: `-s ARGS   --server-args=ARGS        arguments (other than server number and "-nolisten tcp") to pass to the Xvfb server (default: "-screen 0 640x480x8")`

Comment: Do you want to try `xvfb-run  -s 1920x1080x16 ./myApp`?

Comment: @mueh As far as I understand it, that passes "./myApp" as an arg to Xvfb, and when I tried it, xvfb-run says `Xvfb failed to start`. Unless I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: ok. As our `xvfb-run` are so different, can you edit your original post with your OS and version.

Comment: @mueh sure thing.

Comment: I have a debian jessie on a raspberry pi, so I tried its `xvfb-run`. It is not too different. The final answer seems to be 1) you need `./myApp` last, and 2) the `-s` option needs a quoted string eg: `-s  '-screen 0 1920x1080x16'`.

Comment: @mueh Aha! It was the quotations I was missing. That was dumb. Thanks.